# Head movement detection - iOS

Tags: ios, camera

Someone asked me if is it possible to detect the head movement of someone using the iPhone's camera. It's because that the person wants to detect when his head touches some random objects falling from above.

[This game](http://www.juegosgratis.ca/juegos/Dominar-la-pelota/) represents almost what I'm trying to say. Is it possible to use the camera to detect someone's head movement or other part of the body to avoid the ball touching the ground? Not using your fingers over the screen, or the movement of the device.

Do you think it could possible? Because I haven't see any app / game using someone's movement. And if is possible in iOS... would it be possible to do it on Android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's all about algorithm (and after that - processing power of the device). I'm quite positive that it is possible (I have seen a demo with webcam & laptop), but I don't know about algorithm/library that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Apple demo code, it's pretty close to what you're after:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html